# Correct type of async action in redux with redux-thunk middleware

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have created simple react App during learning middleware redux-thunk. I have a problem with transpilation because of incorrect type of async action fetchPosts in interface PostListProps.

Below I show all code of the functional component where is the problem:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions'
import Action from '../actions/actionTypes'
import { Dispatch } from "react";
import State from '../reducers/State'

interface PostListProps { 
    fetchPosts: () => (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => Promise<void>
}

const PostList = (props: PostListProps) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchPosts()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>Post List</div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => {
    return { posts: state.posts };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { fetchPosts }
)(PostList);
```

My code is transpiled without error only when I change type of fetchPosts function to:

`fetchPosts: () => any`

Below I present code of function fetchPosts:

```
import Action, { ActionType } from "./actionTypes";
import jsonPlaceholder from "../apis/jsonPlaceholder";
import { Dispatch } from "react";
import Post from '../apis/Post'
import State from "../reducers/State";
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

export const fetchPosts = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
        const response: AxiosResponse<Post[]> = await jsonPlaceholder.get<Post[]>('/posts')
        dispatch({type: ActionType.FETCH_POSTS, payload: response.data });
    }
}
```

The error is like below:
[image]

I have no idea where can be a problem? Why my type of fetchPosts() is wrong? I would like to find out.
I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is not concerned with the details of how the posts get fetched and dispatched to the store, so the `dispatch` bit doesn't need to be reflected in the interface. All the needed wiring is handled by `react-redux`.

Try this:

```
interface PostListProps {
    fetchPosts: () => void;
}
```

Notice that `Promise` is not mentioned in the interface as your component doesn't await it anyway.

As to how to correctly type the `dispatch` function, we could infer the proper type from the `store` instance:

```
import thunk, { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk';

interface AppState {
    posts: PostsState;
    claims: ClaimsState;
}

type AppAction = PostsAction | ClaimsAction;

type AppThunk = ThunkMiddleware<AppState, AppAction>;

const reducer: Reducer<AppState, AppAction> = combineReducers({
  posts: postsReducer,
  claims: claimsReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk as AppThunk)
);

// the type is inferred as
// Dispatch<AppAction> & ThunkDispatch<AppState, undefined, AppAction>
type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Slice-specific state and action types would be defined in corresponding slices, something like this:

```
// posts slice
export type PostsState = Post[];
export type PostsAction =
    | FetchPostsAction
    | FetchPostsFulfilledAction
    | FetchPostsRejectedAction;

// claims slice
export type ClaimsState = Claim[];
export type ClaimsAction =
    | CreateClaimsAction;
```

You might also want to take a look at the [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) package, where much of these has been taken care of.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I have another problem. I can't see the posts. They are undefined inside of my PostComponent. Here is my repo: https://github.com/pirx1988/redux-thunk-posts

Comment: You should check your `combineReducers()` call. It should be `combineReducers({ posts: postReducer })` rather than just `combineReducers({ postReducer })`. The latter creates a wrong state shape, `{ postReducer: [] }`.